# Can't make BizTalk .btm map file changes, exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013

I have some BizTalk source code I'm trying to modify, it's about 2 years old.  It's working fine in the test environment.

I make any change to the map, I mean ANY change to the map, the file format gets wildly different.  The 2015 version has nicely organized carriage returns and in the new file it's flat.

The other thing I noticed is that in the 2 year old code, the .btm header contains **BizTalkServerMapperTool_Version="2.0"**  and when I edit in VStudio and save it says **BizTalkServerMapperTool_Version="3.0"**

The 2.0 version, when deployed works, the 3.0 version does not.

This is a showstopper for me as I am unable to edit any biztalk maps in the solution, any change once in the test server errors out with "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation"

Any assistance troubleshooting this would be greatly appreciated.

I am in the process of updating to CU5, but that process said "custom action failed", so who knows if CU5 even got in properly.

If upload the maps is helpful I might do that, but they are very large, it's an X12 EDI project.

Comment: are you sure the map was initialy created for the same BizTalk Server version?

Comment: A) Are you absolutely sure you're using the same version of the BizTalk design to edit the Map?  B) How would you even notice the carriage returns?  You should not be seeing the .btm code directly.

Comment: Your BTM file in fact is just a facade for an XSLT file. Comparing the XSLT output before/after the so-called "change" might give you some kind of indication as to why this happens. You can view the output XSLT by right-clicking your BTM file and choosing "Validate map"